# nested mongodb query with moped/mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, moped

I'd like to write some nested queries using mongodb, but I'm very new with mongoid/moped. For the sake of the example, would it be acceptable to write some *friends of friends* query as follows ?

```
u1 = User.last # get some user
friends_of_friends = u1.friends.map do |friend|
                       User.find(friend.id).friends.map(&:name)
                     end
```

Or perhaps

```
u1 = User.last # get some user
friends_of_friends = u1.friends.flat_map(&:friends)
```

I'm pretty confident that these query would work. What I don't know however, is wether a single query is passed to mongo, or several ones ?

- What I want : "compile" the query, send it, and get results => one database call, awesomeness is ensured
- What I do not want : Find user 1, return an array of results, and for each found user, perform a new friend request => lot of database calls, loss of performances and definitely not awesome !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I recommend that you write a test.  Then (1) truncate log/test.log, (2) run the test, (3) examine log/test.log, and you can see the "MOPED" queries that correspond to your test.  Make changes to your test and iterate with steps 1-3 above.